# AngularJS: Pushing to array does not work

Tags: angularjs

I have an empty array that I'm just pushing integers into. However, the `console.log`s print am empty array `[ ]` everytime I trigger this function in my view:

html:

```
<div ng-repeat="color in colors">
  {{color.name}} <input type="checkbox" ng-model="color_ids" ng-change="toggleColorFilter(color.id)">
</div>
```

angular:

```
app.controller('IndexCtrl', ['$scope', "Product", "Color", function($scope, Product, Color) {

  ...
  $scope.color_ids = [];


  $scope.toggleColorFilter = function(color_id) {
    var index = $scope.color_ids.indexOf(color_id);
    if (index > -1) {
      $scope.color_ids.push(color_id);
    } else {
      $scope.color_ids.splice(index, 1);
    }
    console.log($scope.color_ids);
  };


}]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `if` logic is backwards - it's saying that if the color id exists - then push it, else, splice a non-existent value...flip the logic:

```
if (index > -1) {
  $scope.color_ids.splice(index, 1);
} else {
  $scope.color_ids.push(color_id);
}
```

Comment: It worked!! but why? If the index is -1 that means it exists in the array??

Comment: If the index is greater than `-1` - it exists - so you want to splice it. If the index equals -1 it doesnt exist.

Comment: ... how did I miss that. I need to step away from the computer for a few minutes. thanks!!